# What is compton's edge equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, kinematics, textbook-erratum

Is this a typo of Compton's edge equation in my textbook? It says "the Compton edge, that a recoiling electron can carry away from a Compton scattering event is given by":

$$E_k = \frac{hf}{1+mc^2/(2hf)} = \frac{2E^2}{2E+mc^2}$$

I've tried deriving this many times, but i end up getting the equation: $$\frac{hf}{-1+mc^2/(2hf)}$$

Is this the correct one?

Comment: Note that the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_edge) gives the deflected photon's energy as $E_\text{photon, final} = E_\text{photon, initial} / \left( 1 + \frac{E_\text{photon, initial}}{m_ec^2} (1-\cos\theta) \right)$, which I think is different from *both* of your options.

Comment: which textbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your textbook is correct. In Compton scattering,

$$E'=\frac{E}{1+\frac{E}{m c^2}(1-\cos{\theta})}$$

where $E$ is the initial photon energy, $E'$ is the final photon energy, $m$ is the electron mass, and $\theta$ is the scattering angle.

For a given $E$, $E'$ is minimum when $\theta=\pi$,

$$E'_\text{min}=\frac{1}{1+2\frac{E}{m c^2}},$$

and this maximizes the energy transferred to the electron, $E-E'$:

$$(E-E')_\text{max}=E-E'_\text{min}=E\left(1-\frac{1}{1+2\frac{E}{m c^2}}\right)=E\left(\frac{2\frac{E}{m c^2}}{1+2\frac{E}{m c^2}}\right)=\frac{2E^2}{2E+m c^2}.$$

This maximum transferred energy is the *Compton edge*.

Comment: Yes, I derived it a different way and somehow arrived at the correct result